# iOS Crash on Google Sign-In v6.0.1

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm migrating to Google Sign-In v6.0.1 from v5.0.2 on iOS and have been unable to resolve the following crash. I can see it's crashing before triggering the callback, but not much else.

**Crash**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GIDSignIn signInWithConfiguration:presentingViewController:callback:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003751e80'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (9F5AB4F7-9E7C-4FD7-BB85-8251599DC05C) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

**Code**

```
let clientId = "<MY_CLIENT_ID>"
let configuration = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientId)
...
signInInstance.signIn(with: configuration, presenting: presentingViewController) { [weak self] user, error in
    self?.handleSignIn(user, error)
}
```

Comment: How is `signInInstance` defined? Can you see what's the object to which selector was sent? You need to use `po 0x600003751e80` (replace with new address which you'll see after the crash) in the console to check it.

Comment: @Philip, It's stored as a property on init: `private var signInInstance = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance`. `(lldb) po 0x600003085380
<GIDSignIn: 0x600003085380>`